# Android Terminal does not work immediately after reboot

Tags: terminal

`jackpal.androidterm`  does not work immediately after starting the phone.

Instead, it first just shows a blank screen. Then I need to wait around 20 to 60 seconds. **Then,** the terminal's prompt is enabled.

Comment: Please don't post exact duplicate questions. Instead, [edit] this question to add more info and context as best as you can, like the device model and Android version, are you using custom ROM or not, etc. Also, you might be interested in reading [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)